# Windows entry in Grub with two hard disks

Tags: dual-boot

I have two SSDs in my machine. One has Ubuntu and the other has Windows. After a recent update, the Windows entry was removed from Grub. Both disks and OSs are still bootable from Bios, but I'd prefer to bring the Windows entry back in Grub. I've run `os-prober` several times and it doesn't find Windows.

How can I bring it back?

If it's helpful, here's a snippet of the output from lsblk showing both drives:

```
nvme1n1     isw_raid_membe 476.9G                                    
└─md126                        0B                                    
nvme2n1     isw_raid_membe  27.3G                                    
└─md127                        0B                                    
nvme0n1                    465.8G                                    
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat             512M /boot/efi                          
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4           465.3G /
```

I'm happy to provide any additional information that may be helpful.

Comment: Windows updates may reset UEFI settings or may update UEFI resetting UEFI settings. Double check that Windows fast start up/hibernation was not turned on.  Grub only boots working Windows and then Windows cannot be hibernated or encrypted.

Comment: No dice. Disabled, rebooted, ran `os-prober` and `update-grub`. Still not detecting Windows.

Comment: To see details of your configuration: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/